# How to properly create a temp file for opening in windows?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Ok, I have a bit of code that works fine for quite some time. However on one site, our users are reporting an error and it is specific to an rtf documents but I cannot see how or why the error is related to that extension.

```
            string filename = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName() + "." + fileext;
            File.WriteAllBytes(filename, filecontent);

            var process = Process.Start(filename);
```

The error is this one:

```
UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Users\admargosy\AppData\Local\Temp\180\tmp3D08.tmp.rtf' is denied.
Inner exception stack:
System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
System.IO.File.InternalWriteAllBytes(String path, Byte[] bytes, Boolean checkHost)
```

Users have so far confirmed that there are no issues if it's an pdf file. It opens fine. Rtf files get stuck with this error. I kinda need ides how to analyze this or an idea what is going on here.

Application is in WinForms and is being run remotely on Terminal Server.

Comment: Probably too localized and can't really be answered. But, look at the ACLs for those rtf files and see what the permissions are. You might have to fix the permissions and try again, and then see if the issue returns.

Comment: Rtf files reside in a database. This method creates an temp file just so the user can see the content. By using GetTempFileName I expect that I should encounter no issues with permissions.

Comment: As would I, but troubleshooting. Perhaps however these files were created accidentally set the perms weirdly. Permissions can be stored in the filestream you are using for example. Or maybe some groups malware scanner did something screwy *once*. Either way, I'd start with researching the problem and not the code as your code here is very cut and dry, standard and shouldn't do this.

Comment: That `180` in file name doesn't match the line you show. Why would `GetTempFileName` create subfolder (see [sources](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/path.cs,1134))?

Comment: You are kindof abusing the `GetTempFileName()` method in a way that could possibly result in you using a temp file that already existed (because you are adding a suffix to the temp file name, and Windows didn't check for an existing file with that name). This is unlikely to cause an issue in practice, but just to be on the safe side, what happens if you create the temp file name as follows? `string filename = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N")) + "." + fileext;`

Comment: @MatthewWatson I'll try adding a GUID. You're right. I'm thinking maybe there is a chance that method returns the same tmp file name since it doesn't exist. But the tmp + extension is still there.

Answer (score 2):

This code works for me:

```
string fileext = "txt";
byte[] filecontent = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello, world!");
string filename = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName() + "." + fileext;
File.WriteAllBytes(filename, filecontent);
var process = Process.Start(filename);
```

It writes the text `Hello, world!` to a temp `.txt` file and opens it via the shell (which will likely open in Notepad on clean systems.)

---

#### In your example code and associated error:

I would investigate how the `\180\` fragment got into your path.  It shouldn't be there given the code you provided.  Something's fishy about your example.

> `C:\Users\admargosy\AppData\Local\Temp\180\tmp3D08.tmp.rtf`

I was expecting `GetTempFileName` to return something that looks more like `C:\Users\admargosy\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp3D08.tmp`

Comment: I didn't give much thought about that fragment. I figure it's part of the implementation. But another user said that i'm cheating in a way since i'm adding extension to the file name. The method checked and created a file without an extension.

Comment: @Nezreli Yeah, it's a little like cheating.  It's like going to a hotel and asking for an unoccupied room, they tell you "room 345 is free", and you say, "ok, I'll take room 3456".